# Loop being strainge

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination, wp-reset-query

So I hacked together a function that does the following:

```
protected function _query_post($query){
    $original = $this->_wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($query);

    if($wp_query->have_posts()){
        while($wp_query->have_posts()){
            $wp_query->the_post();

            $this->_title($this->_options);

            the_excerpt();
        }

        next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries');
        previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;');
    }

    $wp_query = $original;  
}
```

So it's not hard to tell what's going on - all were doing is displaying a list of posts that are queried. The query used here is:

```
'posts_per_page' => 20
```

This then created the [following page (scroll down) with a a pagination at the bottom](http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/).

The problem is, try going through pages 1 - 5. The posts are all the same....At the bottom of the post I do a reset of the query.....

Any ideas?

Comment: See [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) `format` parameter.

Comment: That doesnt even come close to answering my question. Did you try out the link? cycle through the various "pages"? see how none of the posts change but the page numbers do?

Please be more detailed.

Comment: It is pretty close. You are using pretty permalinks and in the same time you use default `format` value. Just follow the link. And there is some dirt in your code. http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/?page=3 does not redirect to http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/page/3, but http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/?paged=3 do.

Comment: I have been reading the link, how ever I am not sure what I need to change. Do you have any examples?

Comment: The pagination is working as expected but the posts dont change when you go to older posts, or page/2 page/3 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have the current page number in your $query array?

for example:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$query = array( 'paged' => $paged );
```

Comment: With that now, check out the link,going to page 2, 3, 4 or 5 causes there to be blank and empty pages.

Comment: can you share the $query array you are using?

Comment: just as simple: 'posts_per_page' => 20

Comment: and **$query=array('posts_per_page' => 20,'paged'=>$paged);**  gives you empty pages? You could also check out some manual pages: **$query=array('posts_per_page' => 20,'paged'=>4);**

Comment: cant do paged=>4 because what if there's more then 4 pages? it gives me empty pages AFTER page one, WITH 'paged' => $paged

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue, how ever the main problem is that queried posts - display the same set of posts across all pages, where as non queried posts, when you paginate through the posts are different.

Comment: I was testing your site paging, and it seems to be working now. What did you change since last time?

Comment: ps: sometimes using the pre_get_posts hook can be easier when dealing with paging.  See more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: ps: you are adding a secondary loop, but using the paging of the main loop, I think that might result in a mismatch of the total number of pages.